# Is there a penalty for bruising oranges?

Tags: part-time-ufo

In the first level of *Part Time UFO*, there are 3 oranges you can load into the farmer’s truck for extra cash. These oranges can become bruised if you drop them on the ground, but they still give extra cash if delivered.

Is there a penalty for bruising oranges? Or is the bonus the same either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bruised item is only worth $10 when delivered. This applies to any bruised item, whether it be oranges or dinosaur bones. (Not all item types can be bruised).

Other than earning a smaller payment, bruising items does not seem to affect gameplay or ranking.